# "jQuery is not defined" error when moving Wordpress installation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, migration

I've been searching all over Stackoverflow about this issue but none of the solutions seem to work.
I migrated an existing wordpress installation (database + files, same domain) to  to another hosting.
These are the errors i'm getting, all jquery related: Uncaught SyntaxError:

> Invalid or unexpected token
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

[screenshot of errors in wp-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol524.png)

I tried to add **"define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);" to wp-config.php** and **add Jquery script tags directly to theme's header.php file**

Can you please guide me with this problem?

Link to frontend: https://www.cartediem.be

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the jquery file is currupted somehow (maybe during migration). Can you try and replace the "wp-admin" folder contents with the files from fresh wordpress download or relevant wordpress version. Perhaps that will solve your issue.

Comment: @zipkundan I replaced wp-admin folder with fresh files, but noticed no changes. Could it have something to do with permissions?

Comment: Did you happen to change the order of declaration of script dependencies. Javascript relies heavily on script execution order. If any scripts are referenced that require JQuery, before JQuery itself is defined (in sequential order), then the loaded script will complain that JQuery is not defined.

Comment: @Asyranok no, not that i know about. Should i try and add "wp_enqueue_script()"? I researched a bit about it and come to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is clearly wrong with your jquery.js (and probably not only that). it looks to me like some weird error with the charset of the filesystem. or a corrupted file/transfer, like zipkundan mentioned. But you said you replaced the files.

i copied the code of your jquery.js directly into the console. same error like you get.

then i copy the code of one of my installations (same jquery version) the same way, and it works.

Take a look at the screenshot, on the left is mine, on the right is yours. This MIGHT also be a problem when unzipping the installation or transferred files. try to upload the individual files via FTP.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it Beatroot! I never zipped the files. I just uploaded them all via FTP. I uploaded the "wp-includes/js" folder again to check if it was a corrupted js file but to no avail. Then I noticed that my database collation is set to "latin1_swedish_ci" (default when creating a database) while the table collation is set to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci". Could this be the charset error? (Changing the database collation to "tf8mb4_unicode_ci" didn't solve it.)

Comment: the database collation has definetely nothing to do with the problem in jquery.js. are you uploading from a fresh wordpress download or from the backup you made? if the second, replace all wordpress with a fresh download. or, just replace jquery.js with the one in a fresh download. at some point i would take it to the hoster. it's a reproducible problem.  open jquery.js from the first error message, copy the code, paste it into the console. if there's an error, the problem persists. also you can see the charset problem when scrolling a bit to the right in the devtools.

Comment: this looks more and more like a server-side configuration problem. you might want to try the tips here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset  add this to your htaccess
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
But i'm not sure about this one. If above works, also take it to the hoster. For sure: a fresh downloaded js file for wordpress should not cause you problems like this.

Comment: I tried to replace all the wordpress files with a fresh download, including the theme! and that seemed to be to solution. No more jquerry errors! Thanks!!